# What should I name my polymorphic association?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, polymorphic-associations

I have two models `Listing` & `Building`. Both will have an `Amenity`.

I want to create a polymorphic association between Amenity & the other two models, but I am not quite sure how to name it.

I was thinking of doing `has_amenities`, but that may be awkward if rails is creating a `has_amenities_type` column as the reference.

An amenity is like: granite counter top, pool, etc.

How should I approach this?

All the examples I see of polymorphic associations revolved around `imageable, commentable, etc.`

So not quite sure what to do here. `amenitable`? That seems.....wrong.

Comment: It's a bit long winded, but how about can_have_amenities? That's essentially what imageable / commentable / xxxable are saying, but it doesn't sound quite so weird as amenitable...

Comment: Hrmm...good suggestion, but then I would be doing `has_many :amenities, :as => :can_have_amenities`? Hrmm....definitely a bit long winded, but maybe can work.

Comment: This is true, but it is relatively well hidden (it would only be mentioned in the column names, and the association definition), it's not perfect though...

Comment: Ok....I will use it. Put it as an answer and I will accept it.

Comment: Okay thank you, I've just put it as the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a bit long winded, but how about `can_have_amenities`? That's essentially what imageable / commentable / xxxable are saying, but it doesn't sound quite so weird as amenitable...